# Local SQL Server connection fail

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sqlconnection

I'm trying to connect to a local SQL Server database file and do not know if connection string is right:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ma\Documents\mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT plataform FROM plataforms", con);

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(myDataSet);
```

I have such code wrapped in a try catch and always throws this exception:

> Reference to object not established as an instance of an object

What's wrong?

**EDIT**:

Sorry, I have been commenting code to see what line arises such error and it's the following:

```
DataRowCollection drc = myDataSet.Tables["plataforms"].Rows;
```

Sorry, I made a wrong question.

Comment: Can you please share the exception description?

Comment: @Arulkumar It shows: Reference to object not established as an instance of an object

Comment: Executes the `SELECT plataform FROM plataforms` in your SQL Server Management studio returns any data?

Comment: There is no need to execute that query in SSMS, the error is not the SERVER error

Comment: @Arulkumar, yes, data is displayed with such query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If you have only a single result set anyway - then I'd recommend just using `DataTable` (instead of `DataSet`) to put the results into

Comment: @marc_s I was trying that and now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think You must `open` connection before `Fill`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ma\Documents\mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT plataform FROM plataforms", con);

SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
dAdapter.SelectCommand = sda;
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
try {
      con.Open();
      sda.Fill(myDataSet);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw (ex);
   } finally {
      con.Close();
   }
```

you can try this code.

Comment: Hi, I included the open connection and arises the same error.

Comment: No you don't - the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` method will itself open the connection, if necessary.